# How to get rid of "No match found" when running "rm *"

Tags: zsh, wildcards, rm

Using `zsh`, I get a "No match found" message when choosing a pattern that does not fit with `rm` and that even when redirecting the output.

```
# rm * > /dev/zero 2>&1
  zsh: no matches found: *
```

How can I get rid of this message?

Comment: Are you trying to delete everything in the current directory? What is the current directory?

Comment: You could use `setopt extended_glob` (or even plain `rm * >/dev/null 2>&1`) but really you should make a workaround to not need `rm *`, that's outright dangerous

Comment: You should really be sinking to `/dev/null` rather then `dev/zero`. Also, your _stderr_ redirect is missing an `&`; it should be `2>&1`.

Comment: The error message is generated by `zsh` during evaluation of the command and not during the runtime of the command itself (due to the error the command is not even run). The output redirections here would only affect the output of the command and not the shell itself.

Answer (score 111):

This behaviour is controlled by several of [Zsh's globbing options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing). By default, if a command line contains a globbing expression which doesn't match anything, Zsh will print the error message you're seeing, and not run the command at all. You can disable this in three different ways:

- `setopt +o nomatch`

  will leave globbing expressions which don't match anything as-is, and you'll get an error message from `rm` (which you can disable using `-f`, although that's a bad idea since it will force removals in other situations where you might not want to);
- `setopt +o nullglob`

  will delete patterns which don’t match anything (so they will be effectively ignored);
- `setopt +o cshnullglob`

  will delete patterns which don’t match anything, and if all patterns in a command are removed, report an error.

The last two override `nomatch`. All these options can be unset with `setopt -o …`.

`nullglob` can be enabled for a single pattern using [the `N` glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), *e.g.*:

```
rm -f -- *(N)
```

Comment: `nomatch` is less than ideal, that's what Bourne-like shells do. If the pattern doesn't match, it is passed as-is to `rm` (!) upon which `rm` will give an error, or worse could delete the wrong file for a pattern like `*.[ch]` for instance!

Comment: What if I don't want to disable the message, but I would like to continue without error? Like is, there a way to make the nomatch behavior simply print a warning rather than erroring?

Comment: @RaleighL. I’m not aware of any way of doing that.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with zsh's glob qualifiers, they must come at the **end** of the glob pattern. e.g., `*.sh(N)`, not `*(N).sh`. [SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102754/zsh-glob-qualifiers-in-middle-of-path), [manual ref](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)

Answer (score 21):

What would you want it to do instead? Not run `rm` at all (1)? Run it with a literal `*` argument like in other Bourne-like shells (2)? Run it with no argument at all (3)?

1. `files=(*(N)); (($#files)) && rm -- $files`. Or `(rm -- *) 2> /dev/null` but that would also hide genuine errors by `rm` which would be silly. You could discard the `zsh` error but restore stderr for the `rm` command though with `(rm -- * 2>&3 3>&-) 3>&2 2> /dev/null`
2. `emulate sh -c 'rm -- *' 2> /dev/null`. Then like in `sh` which `zsh` now emulated for that single command line, the non-matching `*` is passed as-is to `rm` and `rm` complains as that `*` file doesn't exist. We suppress `rm`'s stderr as you would do in `sh` to suppress that error message,  but again, that's silly as it would hide genuine errors by `rm` as opposed to the error incurred by the misbehaviour of `sh` passing a literal `*` to `rm`. `rm -f '*'` would not complain about an un-existing `*` file though, so you could do `emulate sh -c 'rm -f -- *'`
3. `rm -- *(N)`. `rm` would complain though when not passed any argument, though again, not `rm -f`: `rm -f -- *(N)`.

Generally, `rm -f` is the command you want to use if you want all the files gone and only get an error if files could not be removed or IOW are still there after `rm` has returned. You also generally want to use `-f` in scripts to avoid the user being prompted under some situations.

Here, calling `rm` when the glob doesn't match is wrong. The `sh`<sup>1</sup> behaviour is wrong. It's harmless for a pattern like `*`, but for one like `*.[ch]`, passing `*.[ch]` as-is when it doesn't match could cause the `*.[ch]` file to be removed by mistake:

```
$ ls
*.[ch]  foo.txt
$ zsh -c 'rm *.[ch]'
zsh:1: no matches found: *.[ch]
$ ls
*.[ch]  foo.txt
$ sh -c 'rm *.[ch]'
$ ls
foo.txt
```

Failing with an error is the most sensible thing to do and is what `zsh` (and `fish`, `csh`, `tcsh`, `bash -o failglob` and the original Unix shell) does.

And if you want to take care yourself of that special case, `zsh` makes it easy with its `(N)` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (for *nullglob*) like in case (1) above. `fish` (at least in [recent version](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2394)) makes it even easier as its globs are expanded in a *nullglob* fashion when in arguments to the `set` command (the one that assigns variables). So, the equivalent there, would be:

```
set files *
if count $files > /dev/null
  rm -f -- $files
end
```

See [Why is nullglob not default](/q/204803) for more details.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>. Strictly speaking it's only `sh` since the Bourne shell (since Unix V7 in 1979); earlier versions of `sh` (which did call `/etc/glob` upon unquoted wildcards which is where the *glob* name comes from) did behave like `csh` or `zsh -o cshnullglob`, that is `/etc/glob` would abort the command if none of the globs had any match (and would suppress the non-matching globs if at least one of them had any match). The behaviour was *broken* by the Bourne shell.</sub>

Comment: I think he expects to get the error message from `rm` and not from the shell. Something like "rm: cannot remove `*': No such file or directory".

Comment: @Emmanuel, then that's 2: `emulate sh -c 'rm -- *'` to get the (buggy IMO) behaviour of the Bourne shell.

Comment: @Stephane_Chazelas  as it is written, 2 is the right answer to a question he didn't asked :).

Comment: @Emmanuel, all 3 answer the question: how to get rid of the "No match" error. The OP's code suppresses the `rm` errors. That's something you would do in other shells to suppress the error when there's no matching file and that causes the suppression of genuine rm errors as well. My answer outlines that and hopefully shows how zsh behaviour is preferable.

Comment: what does `--` do?

Comment: @baggiponte, see [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376)

Comment: thank you! I am not great at finding questions containing "symbols". You wrote that `(N)` is a `glob qualifier` - how's it different from `*`?

Comment: @baggiponte, see [`info zsh qualifiers`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). See also [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Comment: @baggiponte Note that `(N)` _qualifies_, i.e. changes, the preceding `*`, so the full pattern is `*(N)`.  The qualifier changes the way the pattern behaves, and in this case the qualifier makes the pattern disappear if there is no match.

Comment: thank you for the comment! I played around with `*(N)` and OMG is zsh so cool! I used it to update a function I have [here](https://github.com/baggiponte/dotfiles/blob/3ddfabbb1d8a846f0275ab3a2a331f22b931269a/zsh/include/functions.zsh#L97)

Comment: @baggiponte, don't use `a && b || c` as replacement for `if a; then b; else c; fi`. That's not correct.

Comment: will do, thank you! I naively added it on the fly - it was only `a && b` but I wanted to add a message in case I did not run the command. tank you very much once again!

Comment: @baggiponte, note that `"$(dirname $HOMEBREW_BUNDLE_FILE)"` or its more correct `"$(dirname -- $HOMEBREW_BUNDLE_FILE)"` is just `$HOMEBREW_BUNDLE_FILE:h` in zsh (like in csh).

Comment: that's so interesting! where can I find more about `:h`?

Comment: @baggiponte, `info zsh modifiers`

Comment: To answer the question "What would you want it to do instead?" consider this. Some job leaves some `*.foo`, `*.bar`, `*.err` files around. The `.err` files are only emitted when some failure conditions occur. What I want to do is simply `rm *.foo *.bar *.err`, I don't care of some of those files do not exist. Now that I know, I guess I can simply `rm *.foo(N) *.bar(N) *.err(N)`.

Comment: @JohnSchmitt, use `rm -- *.(foo|bar|err)` or `cshnullglob`

Answer (score 5):

Type this in interactive zsh:

```bash
setopt no_nomatch
rm * > /dev/null 2>&1
setopt nomatch  # `nomatch` is default, see `man zshoptions`
```

For me, `nullglob` and `cshnullglob` do not work

Comment: why do we need to `setopt nomatch` again after the removal? Can we not add `setopt no_nomatch` to `.zshrc`? please share drawbacks of doing so if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

I could not comment due to lack of reputation. As a complement to Stephen Kitt's answer, I have to use `setopt` instead of `setopt +o` for the option to work. I am using zsh 5.9 .

```bash
setopt nullglob
declare -a files=(${SOME_PATH}/*.log)

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    printf "Removing ${f}...\n"
    rm -f "${f}" || printf "Failed to remove ${f}\n"
done
```

If no match is found, the `files` array is empty, and the loop will not be entered, which meets my need perfectly.