# Portable check empty directory

Tags: bash, zsh, wildcards, portability, dash

With Bash and Dash, you can check for an empty directory using just the shell
(ignore dotfiles to keep things simple):

```
set *
if [ -e "$1" ]
then
  echo 'not empty'
else
  echo 'empty'
fi
```

However I recently learned that Zsh fails spectacularly in this case:

```
% set *
zsh: no matches found: *

% echo "$? $#"
1 0
```

So not only does the `set` command fail, but it doesn't even set `$@`. I suppose
I could test if `$#` is `0`, but it appears that Zsh even stops execution:

```
% { set *; echo 2; }
zsh: no matches found: *
```

Compare with Bash and Dash:

```
$ { set *; echo 2; }
2
```

Can this be done in a way that works in bash, dash and zsh?

Comment: Related: [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several problems with that

> ```
> set *
> if [ -e "$1" ]
> then
>   echo 'not empty'
> else
>   echo 'empty'
> fi
> ```

code:

- if the `nullglob` option (from `zsh` but now supported by most other shells) is enabled, `set *` becomes `set` which lists all the shell variables (and functions in some shells)
- if the first non-hidden file has a name that starts with `-` or `+`, it will be treated as an option by `set`. In zsh and some implementations/versions of ksh, that even makes it a command injection vulnerability like when there's a file called `+A[$(reboot)]`. Those two issues can be fixed by using `set -- *` instead.
- `*` expands only non-hidden files, so it's not a test whether the directory is empty or not but whether it contains non-hidden files or not. With some shells, you can use a `dotglob` or `globdot` option or play with a `FIGNORE` special variable depending on the shell to work around that.
- `[ -e "$1" ]` tests whether a `stat()` system call succeeds or not. If the first file is a symlink to an inaccessible location, that will return false. You shouldn't need to `stat()` (not even `lstat()`) any file to know whether a directory is empty or not, only check that it has some content.
- `*` expansion involves opening the current directory, retrieving all the entries, storing all the non-hidden one and sorting them, which is also quite inefficient.

The most efficient way to check if a directory is non-empty (has any entry other than `.` and `..`) in `zsh` is with the `F` glob qualifier (`F` for *full*, here meaning non-empty):

```
if [ .(NF) ]; then
  print . is not empty
else
  print "it's empty or I can't read it"
fi
```

`N` is the `nullglob` glob qualifier. So `.(NF)` expands to `.` if `.` is full and nothing otherwise.

After the `lstat()` on the directory, if `zsh` finds it has a link-count greater than 2, then that means it has at least one subdirectory so is not empty, so we don't even need to open that directory (that also means, in that case we can tell that the directory is non-empty even if we don't have read access to it). Otherwise, zsh opens the directory, reads its content and stops at the first entry  that is neither `.` nor `..` without having to read, store nor sort everything.

With POSIX shells (`zsh` only behaves (more) POSIXly in `sh` emulation), it is very awkward to check that a directory is non-empty with globs only.

One way is with:

```
set .[!.]* '.[!.]'[*] .[.]?* [*] *
if [ "$#$1$2$3$4$5" = '5.[!.]*.[!.][*].[.]?*[*]*' ]; then
  echo "empty or can't read"
else
  echo not empty
fi
```

(assuming no glob-related option is changed from the default (POSIX only specifies `noglob`) and that the `GLOBIGNORE` (for `bash`) and `FIGNORE` (for `ksh`) variables are not set, and that (for `yash`) none of the file names contain sequences of bytes not forming valid characters).

The idea is that in POSIX shells, when a glob doesn't match, it is left unexpanded  (a misfeature introduced by the Bourne shell in the late 70s). So with `set -- *`, if we get `$1` == `*`, we don't know whether it was because there was no match or whether there was a file called `*`.

Your (flawed) approach to work around that was to use `[ -e "$1" ]`. Here instead, we use `set -- [*] *`. That allows to disambiguate the two cases, because if there is no file, the above will stay `[*] *`, and if there is a file called `*`, that becomes `* *`. We do something similar for hidden files. That is a bit awkward because of yet another misfeature of the Bourne shell (also fixed by `zsh`, the Forsyth shell, pdksh and `fish`) whereby the expansion of `.*` does include the special (pseudo-)entries `.` and `..` when reported by `readdir()`.

So to make it work in all those shells, you could do:

```
cwd_empty()
  if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
    eval '! [ .(NF) ]'
  else
    set .[!.]* '.[!.]'[*] .[.]?* [*] *
    [ "$#$1$2$3$4$5" = '5.[!.]*.[!.][*].[.]?*[*]*' ]
  fi
```

In any case, the syntax of `zsh` by default is not compatible with the POSIX sh syntax as it has fixed most of the major issues in the Bourne shell (well before POSIX.2 was first published) in a non-backward compatible way, including that `*` left unexpanded when there's no match (pre-Bourne shells didn't have that issue, `csh`, `tcsh` and `fish` don't either), and `.*` including `.` and `..` but several others like split+glob performed upon parameter or arithmetic expansion, so you can't expect code written in the POSIX sh to always work in `zsh` unless you turn on `sh` emulation.

That `sh` emulation is especially there so you can use POSIX code in `zsh`.

If you want to `source` a file written in POSIX `sh` inside `zsh`, you can do:

```
emulate sh -c 'source ./that-file'
```

Then that file will be evaluated in `sh` emulation and any function declared within will retain that emulation mode.

Comment: Note you need to use `[ path(NF) ]`; `[[ path(NF) ]]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

While zsh's default behaviour is to give an error, [this is controlled by the `nomatch` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation). You can unset the option to leave the `*` in place the way that bash and dash do:

```
setopt -o nonomatch
```

While that command won't work in either of the others, you can just ignore that:

```
setopt -o nonomatch 2>/dev/null || true ; set *
```

This runs `setopt` on zsh, and suppresses the error output (`2>/dev/null`) and return code (`|| true`) of the failed command on the others.

As written it's problematic if there is a file, for example, `-e`: then you will run `set -e` and change the shell options to terminate whenever a command fails; there are worse outcomes if you're creative. `set -- *` will be safer and prevent the option changes.

Answer (score 4):

Zsh's syntax is not compatible with sh. It's close enough to look like sh, but not close enough that you can take sh code and run it unchanged.

If you want to run sh code in zsh, for example because you have an sh function or snippet written for sh that you want to use in a zsh script, you can use the [`emulate` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-emulate). For example, to source a file written for sh in a zsh script:

```
emulate sh -c 'source /path/to/file.sh'
```

To write a function or script in sh syntax and make it possible to run it in zsh, put this near the beginning:

```
emulate -L sh 2>/dev/null || true
```

In sh syntax, zsh supports all POSIX constructs (it's about as POSIX compliant as `bash --posix` or ksh93 or mksh). It also supports some ksh and bash extensions such as arrays (0-indexed in ksh, in bash and under `emulate sh`, but 1-indexed in native zsh) and `[[ … ]]`. If you want POSIX sh plus ksh globs, use `emulate … ksh …` instead of `emulate … sh …`, and add `if [[ -n $BASH ]]; then shopt -s extglob; fi` for the sake of bash (note that this is not local to the script/function).

The native zsh way to enumerate all the entries in a directory except `.` and `..` is

```
set -- *(DN)
```

This uses the [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `D` to include dot files and `N` to produce an empty list if there are no matches.

The portable sh way to enumerate all the entries in a directory except `.` and `..` is a lot more complicated. You need to list dot files, and if you're listing files in the current directory or in a path that isn't guaranteed to be absolute you need take care in case there is a file name that begins with a dash. Here's one way to do it, by using the patterns `..?* .[!.]* *` to list all files except `.` and `..` and removing unexpanded patterns.

```
set -- ..?*
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && ! [ -e "$1" ] && ! [ -L "$1" ]; then shift; fi
set -- .[!.]* "$@"
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && ! [ -e "$1" ] && ! [ -L "$1" ]; then shift; fi
set -- * "$@"
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && ! [ -e "$1" ] && ! [ -L "$1" ]; then shift; fi
```

If all you want to do is to test whether a directory is empty, there's a much easier way.

```
if ls -A /path/to/directory/ | grep -q '^'; then
  echo "/path/to/directory is not empty"
else
  echo "/path/to/directory is empty"
fi
```

Comment: shorter `if ls -A | read q; then echo not empty; else echo empty; fi`

Comment: @user327359, that could fail if the `pipefail` option is on or if all the filenames in the directory end in backslash. In any case using `ls -A` means reading the directory fully and sorting its entries, so is less efficient than using `zsh`'s `F` glob qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

Most portable way would be via `set` and globstar for all POSIX-compliant shells. This has been shown in [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90152/85039) on a related question. I've adapted the method slightly into a function:

```bsh
rm -rf empty_dir/
mkdir empty_dir/
pwd
cd empty_dir/
pwd
dir_empty(){

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/9911082/3701431
    if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
        # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310553/85039
        setopt +o nomatch 
    fi    

    set -- * .*
    echo "$@"
    for i; do
        [ "$i" = "." ] || [ "$i" = ".." ] && continue
        [ -e "$i" ] && echo "Not empty" && return 1
    done
    echo "Empty" && return 0
}
dir_empty
touch  '*'
dir_empty
```

The big problem with `zsh` is that while `ksh` and `bash` behave in more or less consistent manner - that is when we do `set * .*` you will have 3 positional parameters `* . ..` in really empty directory - in `zsh` you will get `* .*` as positional parameters. Luckily at least `for i ; do ... done` to iterate over positional parameters works consistently.  The rest is just iteration and check for existence of the filename, with `.` and `..` skipped.

---

[Try it online in ksh!](https://tio.run/##XZFRS8MwEMff8ymOKptO2rTW4uYQfBnoywQHPjiklDQ1YTZX0tRN3D57zVLZ6vJwSX73v38uyaoWbatL8HUBvKzMd5pLTUm5slMfVOucsPyU2EXq0MXlDyFgxxkIY6r6jtLaZGyFX1wXn7gOGJY0o5NJFIXjaxrfhtFNHLkKWcASfAXe@dviMX2dvSyenucevE/BCK6c5L9xo@QmcO58w0SmPvifexyFSRLTcRLGk0NdzQ1WBq4QFJaZYQJcqpD7SA7BysD3YQTByO05E2hbevA6NWqQU8jxYLu0SenBPXiB7RW22z5xaDAAhspI1fBelc87mct3h8zRdO/q7ZnmptEKurfJUfFeO7NTVUh2xz8gBht7PRiOhkfYtr8)

[Try it online in zsh!](https://tio.run/##XZFRT4MwEMff@ykuaDbFQEEkDhcTX5boy0xc4oOLIaQUaSY9UoqbOj87dsVsuD5c29/9799r@9WUXacq8FQBvKr1Z5oLRUm1MtMQ1OucsPyYmEVq0dn5NyFgxgmUWtfNDaWNztgKP7gq3nHtM6xoRpMkDIPJJY2ug/AqCm2FKGAJngTn9GVxnz7PnhYPj3MHXqegSy6t5L9xK8XGt@58w8pMvvE/9ygM4jiikziIkn1dwzXWGi4QJFaZZiXYVCF2keyDkYHngQu@a/eclWhaunN6NSoQU8hxb7s0SeHALTi@6RW22yGxaDQChlIL2fJBlcd7mc33h8xR9@/q7JjiulUS@rfJUfJBO7NjVUB@Dn9ANLbmejB2xwfYdb8)

Comment: @Three I've adapted the answer to check for `zsh`. Unfortunatelly for us `zsh` decided to go the weird way instead of similar behavior to `bash` or other shells, since according to POSIX: "If the pattern does not match any pathnames, the returned number of matched paths is set to 0, and the contents of pglob->gl_pathv are implementation-defined." [source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/glob.html)

Comment: turning `nomatch` everywhere risks breaking code that assumes the default (and very sensible) setting that `sh` and `bash` get wrong, so the change really should be localized only to this function

Comment: @thrig  Well, considering that so far others haven't found a way to make glob work without `nomatch`, that's the best we got. We can also toggle it back before function exits, of course.  Or we could just abandon shell ways and just use something else, like `find`  for instance.

Comment: @Three I've revised the answer again. Probably this is the best I can do, as `zsh` seems to favor features instead of consistency. Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: The expansion of `.*` not including `.` and `..` is what you generally want and was done in the public domain version of `ksh` before `zsh` (pdksh inherited it from the Forsyth shell on which it is based). In other shells whether `.` and `..` is included depends on whether `readdir()` returns them or not which is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `set *` solution. How about this?

```
dir="./empty"
has_file=false

for i in "$dir"/*; do 
  if test ! "$i" = "$dir/*"; then
    has_file=true
    echo "$i"
  if
done

echo "$has_file"
```

Tested and this works well for `zsh`, `bash`, `ash`, `ksh`, `bourne` AKA `heirloom`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to consider dot files:

```bash
test your_dir/* = "your_dir/*" 2>/dev/null && echo 'empty' || echo 'not empty'
```

Mind the difference between the *path* `your_dir/*` and the *string value* `"your_dir/*"` (without and with double quotes).

1. If "your_dir" is empty then `your_dir/*` returns the (not resolvable) **single string** "your_dir/*", if it is not empty it returns the files and folders in "your_dir" as a **list of strings**
2. If `your_dir/*` returns a list of strings with **more than one element** then **the shell** throws an error "test: too many arguments" which effects to **false** for the whole condition. **In this case you don't want want the shell's output "test: too many arguments" and so suppress it by `2>/dev/null`** (i.e. redirect STDERR (= "2") from default STDOUT to the special purpose device "/dev/null")
3. If `your_dir/*` returns a list of strings with **exactly one element** then this will definitely not match "your_dir/*" and **test** returns **false**
4. If `your_dir/*` returns the string "your_dir/*" (meaning that `your_dir/*` could not be resolved to a list of files) then **test** returns **true**

(Note the easier readable [short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) `&& ... || ..` instead of `if ... ; then ... fi`)