# Error output from ls -A results in error output, why?

Tags: ls, error-handling

I have a script I run regularly using cron. I would like to get notified by email when these scripts fail. I do not wish to be notified every time they run and produce any output at all.

As such, I am using the script [Cronic](https://habilis.net/cronic/) to run my jobs inside cron, which should mean only error output gets sent, and not just *any* output.

However, in one script I have a command like this:

```
if [ "$(ls -A ${local_backup_location}/nextcloud-data/)" ]; then
  # save space by removing diffs older than 6 months
  rdiff-backup --remove-older-than 6M --force ${local_backup_location}/nextcloud-data/ || echo "[$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T")] No existing nextcloud data backup"
fi
```

The `ls -A ${local_backup_location}/nextcloud-data/` is intended to test if a directory is empty. My problem is that this command seems to result in output which is recognized as error output cronic. Cronic defines an error as any non-trace error output or a non-zero result code. For example:

```
Cronic detected failure or error output for the command:
/usr/local/sbin/run_backup

RESULT CODE: 0

ERROR OUTPUT:
appdata_ocgcv9nemegb
files_external
flow.log
flow.log.1
__groupfolders
.htaccess
index.html
nextcloudadmin
nextcloud-db.bak
nextcloud.log
nextcloud.log.1
.ocdata
rdiff-backup-data
Test_User
updater.log
updater-ocgcv9nemegb ]
custom
gitea-db.sql
log ]
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   365    0     0  100   365      0    302  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   303
100   365    0     0  100   365      0    165  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   165
100   365    0     0  100   365      0    113  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   113
100   365    0     0  100   365      0     86  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--    86
100   365    0     0  100   365      0     70  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    70
100   365    0     0  100   365      0     58  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
100   365    0     0  100   365      0     50  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
100   365    0     0  100   365      0     44  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
100   365    0     0  100   365      0     39  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
100   365    0     0  100   365      0     37  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
100 10.4M    0 10.4M  100   365  1016k     34  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 2493k
100 11.6M    0 11.6M  100   365  1128k     34  0:
 00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 3547k

STANDARD OUTPUT:
Maintenance mode enabled
Deleting increment at time:
<snip>
```

So why does the command `ls -A ${local_backup_location}/nextcloud-data/` produce error output in this case, and how can I prevent this? An alternative robust method to test if a directory is empty would be acceptable, but I would also like an explanation of why the command seems to produce error output.

EDIT: Adding Cronic stdout with `set -ex`

Some commenters have requested the actual whole script which is very long, but Cronic reports the actual stdout of the script and I use `set -ex` at the top of the script. The error output happens immediately after the invocation of `ls -A /mnt/reos-storage-2/backups/nextcloud-data/` which is why I believe the error output to be the result of this command.

```
+ rdiff-backup --ssh-no-compression /var/www/nextcloud /mnt/reos-storage-2/backups/nextcloud/
+ ls -A /mnt/reos-storage-2/backups/nextcloud-data/
+ [ 67cf481e-62a3-1039-8bf2-05805d214bca
<removed>
appdata_ocgcv9nemegb
<removed>
<removed>
<removed>
<removed>
files_external
flow.log
flow.log.1
__groupfolders
.htaccess
index.html
<removed>
<removed>
nextcloudadmin
nextcloud-db.bak
nextcloud.log
nextcloud.log.1
.ocdata
<removed>
<removed>
rdiff-backup-data
<removed>
Test_User
<removed>
updater.log
updater-ocgcv9nemegb ]
+ rdiff-backup --remove-older-than 6M --force /mnt/reos-storage-2/backups/nextcloud-data/
+ date +%Y-%m-%d %T
+ echo [2021-04-21 03:23:38] Starting nextcloud data backup
```

Comment: You say you have a command _like_ that. The command that you _show_ does not produce output. Can you please double check that the actual command is identical to what you show in the question?  It looks as if the error output contains an _unsorted_ list of files, which indicates that it's not a list produced by `ls`.  Are you in fact calling `find`?

Comment: @Kusalananda it's plausible output for some locales that don't sort non-alphanumerics

Comment: @roaima Well, it's not the shown command that produces the specific output in any case. Notice how the command substitution is quoted and how the error message contains `]` twice and no actual _error message_. There's also output from `curl` (?), but no `curl` command is shown.

Comment: Ah yes. The last three filenames (`custom`, `gitea-db.sql`, `log`) are out of sequence but the order of the remainder is reproducible under (at least) `en_GB.UTF-8`.

Comment: @crobar, remove any irrelevant parts from that script until you're left with just the part that causes the error. Then post that remaining script _in full_, including the `#!/bin/bash` line and any `set -o errexit` lines etc, and also the cron command you use to launch it. If you think the problem is in the part you quoted, then leave just that, and post the results: the full script and the error output you get. And if the problem doesn't appear after you remove everything else, well, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: My locale is en_GB. I did actually prune the output of the ls command to remove directories with people's names, but I did not change the order of the remaining directories.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I checked, and turns out you were right that the command shown wasn't the exact command run, I had mixed up the part of the script producing the error, I modified the question to show the exact command producing the error.

Comment: @crobar, so, now that you've checked, the output posted there is the output you get for that exact script, right? And it doesn't have anything else? You've just edited the script, but not the output, so it's hard to be sure from the face of it that they match each other. Like someone said, the output contains what looks to be a progress report from `curl`. Does your script use that, or does `rdiff-backup` use it when running `--remove-older-than`? As far as I can tell, `rdiff-backup` does use the `rsync` libraries, but I can find no mention of `curl` in connection with it.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I added the output of the script as reported by Cronic, which also sends the full stdout from the script. I use `set -e` at the top so all commands are echoed. The error output immediately follows the `ls -A` command so I made the assumption that it was responsible for this error output. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Are you always running the script with `set -x`?  Doing so would definitely spam standard error with output.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, I always run with `set -x` I want the script to stop if there's an error of any kind

Comment: @crobar, `set -x` prints all lines the shell runs (the ones starting with the plus). `set -e` is the one that makes the shell exit if a command returns with an error. (Apart from when it doesn't, see e.g. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 )

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes, I was getting mixed up, but yes, I actually want both

Comment: @crobar, yep, just thought to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ [ 67cf481e-62a3-1039-8bf2-05805d214bca
<removed>
[...]
updater.log
updater-ocgcv9nemegb ]
```

This here, is one single command. It's split to multiple lines in the `set -x`/`xtrace` output, because the output from `ls` contains newlines. (Bash would print that with some quotes, Dash doesn't.)

By default, the `xtrace` output goes to stderr, the same as the regular error output, Cronic tries to separate them by looking at the `+`  marker at the start of the `xtrace` lines. That fails here, and it thinks the files names there are part of *regular* error output.

What cronic does is basically this:

> ```
> PATTERN="^${PS4:0:1}\\+${PS4:1}"
> if grep -aq "$PATTERN" $TRACE
> then
>     ! grep -av "$PATTERN" $TRACE > $ERR
> ```

Disabling `xtrace` would be one way to fix that, but it would be a shame to do that since cronic supports it so nicely.

Instead, it might be better to use some other way to check if the directory is empty.

Keeping with `ls -A`, you could pipe the output to `wc` to count the characters there:

```
if [ "$(ls -A "${local_backup_location}/nextcloud-data/" | wc -c)" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "directory not empty"
fi
```

or to `grep`:

```
if ls -A "${local_backup_location}/nextcloud-data/" | grep -q .; then
    echo "directory not empty";
fi
```

Checking if the directory is empty could be done in other ways, within the shell itself, but handling all the corner cases can be hairy. See e.g.
[Portable check empty directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492912/170373)

Comment: `nullglob` and `dotglob` needed for that last bit in bash.

Comment: @Kusalananda, bahh, yes, I wasn't focusing. And they don't even seem to be using Bash, so perhaps `ls -A` will have to do.

Answer (score -1):

If `$gitea_backup_dir` doesn't  exist, or makes `ls` unhappy in any way, `ls` will write an error message to `STDERR`.

You can discard the whole error stream by appending `2>/dev/null` to your command.

IMHO, a better way is:

```
if ([[ -d "$gitea_backup_dir" ]] && \
    [[ $(stat --format="%h" "$gitea_backup_dir") -gt 2 ]] ) ; then
    echo "Nonempty"
else
    echo "Empty"
fi
```

First, check that the directory exists, then see if the number of hard links in the directory (the number of file and subdirectory entries in the directory) is greater than 2 (every directory has at least 2 entries: `.` and `..`).

Comment: Or `set -- "$gitea_backup_dir"/*; if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then ...; fi` (assuming `nullglob` and `dotglob` are set).

Comment: looking at the link count can tell if there's other _directories_ inside the directory, but not files, while the `ls -A` would produce nonempty output if there's anything in the directory, regular files, directories or otherwise, right?

Comment: Both files in a directory and (sub-)directories in a directory  ARE hard links. Don't ask me what `ls -A` would do. It's easy to set up a test environment and try it. Or read `man ls`.

Comment: @waltinator, (was that a reply to me? Use the @-notation, so that people get notifications.) They said that the `ls -A` "is intended to test if a directory is empty", and that's what it does in that if there is at least file in the directory, it prints the name. If there isn't, the output is empty. And yes, files are hard links, but they're hard links to _themselves_, not to the directory. Try e.g. `mkdir foo; ls -ld foo` (the link count should be 2), `touch foo/bar; ls -ld foo` (the link count is still 2), and `mkdir foo/doo; ls -ld foo` (now the link count is 3)